# Using coeftest results in predict.lm() in R

Tags: multiple-regression, prediction, covariance, heteroscedasticity

I am analyzing a dataset in which the variance of the error term in my regression is not constant for all observations. 
For this, I re-built the model, estimating heteroskedasticity-robust (Huber-White) standard errors using the **coeftest** function.
Now, I want to use these new results for a prediction with **predict()** function.

The dataset looks like:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rep(c(10, 15, 20, 25), each = 25)
e <- c()
e[1:25] <- rnorm(25, sd = 10)
e[26:50] <- rnorm(25, sd = 15)
e[51:75] <- rnorm(25, sd = 20)
e[76:100] <- rnorm(25, sd = 25)
y <- 720 - 3.3 * x + e
model <- lm(y ~ x)
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)
coeftest(model, vcov=vcovHC(model, "HC1"))
```

I found the following solution for the issue on the internet:

```
predict.rob <- function(x,vcov,newdata){
    if(missing(newdata)){ newdata <- x$model }
    tt <- terms(x)
    Terms <- delete.response(tt)
    m.mat <- model.matrix(Terms,data=newdata)
    m.coef <- x$coef
    fit <- as.vector(m.mat %*% x$coef)
    se.fit <- sqrt(diag(m.mat%*%vcov%*%t(m.mat)))
    return(list(fit=fit,se.fit=se.fit))}
```

The remaining problem is that my regression has more than 1 regressor.

Is there any way to addapt this resolution to multiple (7) explanatory variables?

Thanks in advance!